# How do I configure spring controller URLs to not have an extension?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, spring-3

My controllers are currently mapped to be something like http://example.com/fix.go and, of course, I think that's idiotic and want something nicer like http://example.com/fix or http://example.com/mmm/fix with no extension.  When I try to configure this, however, I can't get it to work.  I'm clearly missing a key part of understanding on the entire mapping.  I'm using Spring 3.x, tomcat, and annotations for the controllers.

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BooBoo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BooBoo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>   <!-- was *.go when it worked -->
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

BooBoo-servlet.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.foofoo.booboo"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And one of my controllers is configured as such:

```
@Controller
public class BangBangController extends BaseController {

            // Used to be fix.go when it worked
    @RequestMapping( value="fix", method=RequestMethod.GET )
    public ModelAndView choose(
            HttpSession session,
            @RequestParam( value="fixId", required=false, defaultValue="-1" ) Integer fixId,
            @RequestParam( value="forkId", required=false, defaultValue="-1" ) Integer forkId 
    )
    throws Exception { ... }
}
```

I've tried changing the mapping in web.xml to /mmm/* expecting URLs like http://example.com/mmm/fix to work, but that too has not worked.  I get "missing resource" errors when I enter what I think are the correct URLs in the browser.

What am I goofing up here?  What critical piece of understanding do I lack?  I've tried making the no extension thing work on another project at work, and couldn't get it to go there either.  I'm obviously missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your dispatcher servlet is matching anything with a "." in it.

Change it to

```
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

However, that's also bad as you won't be able to serve static content.

What you really should do is this:

```
 <url-pattern>/webapp/*</url-pattern>
```

Where "webapp" is some prefix.  All of your URLs will need to be prefixed with it, but that allows you to still serve static content.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of why /** isn't a good idea (at least not in a dev environment.)  I've also never seen the ** construct before, or documented.

This IS how I thought it should work, more or less, but sadly, this doesn't work for me:

"The requested resource (/booboo/webapp/fix) is not available."

Comment: I wish there was a way I could step through the decisions the Dispatcher is making when it decides what controller it's gonna invoke (or not invoke.)  I mean, short of building Spring myself.

Comment: @Marvo My apologies, I was wrong about the syntax.  I was working from memory and I confused it with a different pattern matcher.  The above edits should work.

Comment: Thanks.  That's more or less how I read it is supposed to work, too.  But I simply cannot make it work.  For my example, where "booboo" is the war/app name, webapp is the pattern as shown in your example, and "fix" is the controller mapping, visiting http://example.com/booboo/webapp/fix doesn't work.  I get "resource() is not available".  (There must be a clue in there that it thinks the resource I've specified is blank (as shown in those parentheses.)  I can only make it work if I specify a suffix.

Comment: @Marvo try changing your request mapping to "/fix"

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help.  Though the message has changed to The requested resource (/booboo/webapp/fix) is not available.  So it got someone's attention.

Comment: @Marvo what does `BaseController` look like?

Comment: Just a constructor.  It's just there because I know eventually I'll want some common methods there.  But now I'm getting log messages at least (with my actual, no faked urls):


DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - DispatcherServlet with name 'j2-applicant' processing GET request for [/jazztwo/app/test]
WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/jazztwo/app/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'j2-applicant'
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request

Comment: I got it working.  I don't know why the change I made fixed things, but it did.  I'll post the working config later when I have more time.  Thanks so much for all the effort, Chris.  Wish I could give you more points.

Comment: Stick with `/*` and use the Spring <mvc:resources...> to configure static content.

Comment: Chris deserves the credit, but anyone coming here should read my answer below to see other necessary parts to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I flubbed up the spring-servlet.xml file by not specifying that I was using the Spring MVC stuff.  I appreciate Chris' help in diagnosing the issue.  I needed confirmation that some of the things I tried (but failed because of this mistake) were correct.

I added

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
```

and

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to that file, and boom, it started working.  What leaves me scratching my head is, "How did it work without that?"  Cuz it worked for *.go patterns.

Here's the resulting file in full:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.barbar.foofoo"/>

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!--
    Declare View Resolver: when view 'view_name' is called (from the Controller), 
    the file '/jsp/view_name.jsp' will be used.
    -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```